# Which op-amp configuration would be recommended?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

A dependent voltage source E2 is changing between 0 and 12 volt. Most of the time it is floating around 12 V but it can go dramatically down sometimes. So this voltage source is not constant, i.e the voltage across R1 is not regulated. L1 in the picture does not interfere with the circuit, it is just a current sensor.

Since my DAQ device's range is maximum 10V,I need to scale this changing voltage maybe to half the amplitude and record it in in time series. So I will connect it to a DAQ board to log the data(I will hook up the Voltage across R1 to DAQ).

I will add an interface(circuitry with an op-amp or something else) between R1 and DAQ in the picture.

I need to satisfy the following conditions:

1-)The interface I will add should drive almost no current. In other words L1 sensor's current measurements should remain almost exactly the same as in the case of the original setup above.

2-)The interface I will add should almost exactly half the E2 voltage so I will have the same time series profile as in the original setup above.

Which op-amp configuration would be recommended?

Comment: Are you sure about R1's value? At 12 volts R1 will draw 12 amps and dissipate 144 watts. Under these circumstances, anything which draws less than about 10 mA will be unnoticeable in terms of current measurement.

Comment: I see.. What if ut was 1k or more?

Comment: If it were 1k, for instance, it would draw 12 mA (12 V/1000), and if "almost no current" means less than 1%, then a buffer impedance of more than 100k would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified a realistic load resistance, so there are 3 possibilities:

1) Do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzRMfr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
where the combination of R2 and R3 will draw 1% more than R1's current. If 1% is too much, increase the multiplying factor.

2) If the DAQ input resistance is too low (less than, let's say, 100 times R2 or R3) then your measurement scale factor will be smaller than you think. In this case, buffer the DAQ with something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI0wRb.png)</sup>
3) Finally, if R1 is too large, so R2 and R3 get too large, you can buffer the input, and do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSXPTM.png)</sup>
but note that OA1 must be either a rail-to-rail op amp with a power supply of greater than the maximum input voltage, or a "regular" op amp with voltage supplies at least 3 volts higher than the maximum input.

Comment: For 1. case: if R1 is 1ohm, you suggested R2 and R3 should be 50ohm. But why not they can be both 1Kohm or even more. Wouldnt they draw less current?? Why 50??

Comment: 50 because I'm assuming you only need 1% accuracy. The two resistors in series will total 100 R, and therefor will draw 1/100 the current that R does, and will only produce a 1% inaccuracy in the current measurement.